# Как исключить из сортировки таблицу в html таблице. Django/HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-template

У меня есть таблица, в которой я вывожу данные с помощью Django template. Я нашел код JS для сортировки таблиц, но из-за того что у меня есть еще одна таблица в HTML внутри первой (которую можно увидеть при нажатии на <div class="col-12 text-center") сортирует именно вторую. Как ее исключить из сортировки? Как только удаляю из HTML "внутреннюю" таблицу все в порядке и сортировка отрабатывает как надо.

```js
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const theads = document.querySelectorAll(".table thead");
        theads.forEach(thead => thead.addEventListener("click", evt => getSort(evt)));

        function getSort({ target }) {
            const order = (target.dataset.order = -(target.dataset.order || -1));
            const thList = Array.from(target.parentNode.cells);
            console.log(thList)
            const index = thList.indexOf(target);
            const collator = new Intl.Collator(["en", "ru"], { numeric: true });
            const comparator = (index, order) => (a, b) => {
                return (
                    order * // order - переключатель, для того чтобы менять порядок сортировки: "с начала" или "с конца"
                    collator.compare(a.children[index].textContent, b.children[index].textContent)
                );
            };
            const tablesBodies = Array.from(target.closest("table").tBodies);
            console.log(tablesBodies)
            tablesBodies.forEach(tBody => {
                tBody.append(...Array.from(tBody.rows).sort(comparator(index, order)));
            });
            thList.forEach( th => th.classList.toggle("sorted", th === target));
        }
    });
</script>
```

```css
<style>
    th.sorted[data-order="-1"]::after {
        content: "▼"
    }

    th.sorted[data-order="1"]::after {
        content: "▲"
    }
</style>
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Договір<br>Тип</th>
            <th>Пот.<br>Пот</th>
            <th>Валюта</th>
            <th>Джерело</th>
            <th>Дата</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tuda_stories" style="display:none;">
        {% for story in stories %}
        <tr style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
            <td>{{story.dref}}<br>{{story.paw}}</td>
            <td>{{story.ref}}<br>{{story.daw}}</td>
            <td>{{story.curr}}<br>{{story.daw}}</td>
            <td>{{story.donor}}<br>{{story.last_story.status}}</td>
            <td>{{story.dat|date:"d.m.Y"}}</td>
        </tr>
            <td colspan="7" style="padding: 3px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center" onclick="toggleElement('history_' + {{story.id}})">
                            <span class="badge badge-secondary">&#8744;</span> История
                        <span class="badge badge-secondary">&#8744;</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12" style="display: none;" id="history_{{story.id}}">
                        <table class="table-sort table-warning">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Період</th>
                                    <th>Сума</th>
                                    <th>Ісп</th>
                                    <th>Сума за.</th>
                                    <th>Сума об.</th>
                                    <th>Термін проср.</th>
                                    <th>Сума проср.</th>
                                    <th>Кред. транш</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {% for history in dealhistory.all %}
                                <tr class="{% if history.dlamtexp %}table-danger{% elif history.pay == 'Да' %}table-success{% endif %}">
                                    <td>01.{{history.month}}.{{history.year}}</td>
                                    <td>{{history.lim}}</td>
                                    <td>{{history.pay}}</td>
                                    <td>{{history.amtpay}}</td>
                                    <td>{{history.day}}</td>
                                    <td>{{history.amte}}</td>
                                    <td>{{history.fluse}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Когда отрабатывет скрипт выпадает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вот решил залить на codeopen, чтобы более наглядно было видно в чем проблема.

```
// https://inter-net.pro/javascript/sort-table
// https://learn.javascript.ru/dom-navigation

// ParentNode.append
// https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

"use strict";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// Все таблицы в которых будет осуществлена сортировка по thead
        const theads = document.querySelectorAll(".table_sort thead");
        theads.forEach(thead => thead.addEventListener("click", evt => getSort(evt)));

        function getSort({ target }) {
          const order = (target.dataset.order = -(target.dataset.order || -1));
          const thList = Array.from(target.parentNode.cells);
          console.log(order)
          console.log(thList)
          console.log(target)
          const index = thList.indexOf(target);
          const collator = new Intl.Collator(["en", "ru"], { numeric: true });
          const comparator = (index, order) => (a, b) => {
            return (
              order * // order - переключатель, для того чтобы менять порядок сортировки: "с начала" или "с конца"
              collator.compare(a.children[index].textContent, b.children[index].textContent)
            );
          };
          console.log('HEre', target.closest("table").tBodies)
          const tablesBodies = Array.from(target.closest("table").tBodies);
          console.log(tablesBodies)
          tablesBodies.forEach(tBody => {
            tBody.append(...Array.from(tBody.rows).sort(comparator(index, order)));
          });
          thList.forEach( th => th.classList.toggle("sorted", th === target));
        }
});
```

https://codepen.io/dmitriyposypaiko/pen/XWpjdNK?editors=1000